# Which parameters are considered for backpropagation in pyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have a parent module named as Parent and it has 2 child components packed in it. The child modules are defined below the parent component.

```
class Parent(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self,in_features,z_dim, img_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_child1 = Child1 (z_dim, img_dim)
        self.my_child2 = Child2 (in_features)
      

  def forward(self,input):
         input=self.my_child1(input)
         input=self.my_child2(input)    
         return input
  
  def forward1(self,input):
         input=self.my_child1(input)
         return input
         
  def forward2(self,input):
         input=self.my_child2(input)
         return input


class Child2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.child2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features, 128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
            nn.Linear(128, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.child2(x)


class Child1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim, img_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.child1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(z_dim, 256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
            nn.Linear(256, img_dim),
            nn.Tanh(), 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.child1(x)

criterion=nn.BCELoss()
model=Parent(in_features,z_dim, img_dim)
output1=model.forward(noise)
loss=criterion(output1,torch.ones_like(output1))
loss.backward()
```

Now when loss.backward() is called, backpropagation is conducted with respect to which parameters? (Parameters of child1/child2 or both?)

What should I do if I need to conduct backpropagation on any of the child network? Could I take help of forward1() or forward2() method from the Parent module or do I need to call them seperately?

Answer (score 0):

The backpropagation algorithm uses the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to compute the derivatives of the loss function w.r.t all inputs and parameters. It is up to you and how you initialize your [optimizer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer) to determine which parameters are going to be *changed* when calling `optimizer.step()` based on the gradients estimated using the backpropagation.

Comment: I want to build a matrix with the gradients of the parameters.  model.parameters().grad is not working. How to obtain the matrix of derivatives of the weights?

Comment: @Jeet in what way is it "not working"? Besides, it sounds like a new question - why don't you ask it properly?